# Constrained regression in Python with multiple constraints

Tags: python, constraints, regression

I am currently working on setting up a constrained regression in Python using

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.GLM(Y,X)    
model.fit_constrained 

'''Setting the restrictions on parameters in the form of (R, q), where R 
and q are constraints' matrix and constraints' values, respectively. As
for the restriction in the aforementioned regression model, i.e., 
c = b - 1 or b - c = 1, R = [0, 1, -1] and q = 1.'''
```

function from StatsModel but running into some issues when I try to set it up with multiple constraints.  I have seven coefficients, including a constant.  I want to set it up so that a weighted sum of dummy 1 and dummy 2 equals zero and a weighted sum of dummy 3 and dummy 4 equals zero.  To use a single constraint example,

```
results = model.fit_constrained(([0, 0, 0, a, b, 0, 0], 0))
```

where a and b are the weights on dummy 3 and dummy 4 and are variables I've predefined.

If I didn't have the a and b variables, and the dummies were equally weighted, I could just use the syntax

```
fit_constrained('Dummy1 + Dummy2, Dummy3 + Dummy4')
```

but when I try to use a similar syntax using

```
results = model.fit_constrained(([0, 0, 0, a, b, 0, 0], 0),([0, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 0], 0))
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (7,6) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 7 (dim 0)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: This is not in the standard library, so which package are you using to fit your model? I presume `statsmodels`, but it helps to be more explicit.

Comment: apologies, you were right it is statsmodel and I've now updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still not sure which model you are running (posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would certainly help), but the following should work for GLMs. From the [docs](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.fit_constrained.html), we have,

> **constraints** (*formula expression or tuple*) – If it is a tuple, then the constraint needs to be given by two arrays (constraint_matrix, constraint_value), i.e. (R, q). Otherwise, the constraints can be given as strings or list of strings. see t_test for details.

This implies the function call should be along the following lines,

```
R = [[0, 0, 0, a, b, 0, 0],
     [0, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
q = [0, 0]

results = model.fit_constrained((R, q))
```

This should work, but since we do not have your model I do not know for sure if `R * params = q`, which must hold according to the documentation.